# Rails: "Permission denied - /tmp/cache/assets/development/sprockets/..."?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, permissions

When I run a rails app and navigate with browser to them I get an error from `rails`:

```
Permission denied - /path/to/my_rails_app/tmp/cache/assets/development/sprockets/37b5a12047376b10a57191a10d3af30a rails error
```

And I have no such file/folders behind the `./tmp/`. What is the problem?

Answer (score 8):

I experienced this same issue.

> Permission denied @ apply2files

The problem is that `tmp` directory in your **application** directory is not writable to the current user, that is, the current user does not have permission to write to the `tmp` directory in your application directory.

**Here's how I solved it**:

Simply delete the `tmp` directory in your **application** directory with superuser rights:

```
sudo rm -rf tmp
```

Do not recreate the `tmp` directory again, it's a waste of effort

Simply start your **application** and the `tmp` directory will be created automatically again:

```
rails s
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 5):

The user who created or 'owns" the my_rails_app directory isn't writable by the server.

```
chown -R webserveruser:webserveruser /path/to/my_rails_app
```

Change the webserveruser to http, or apache or whatever username is running your server.  The entitiy to the right of the : is the group, use a group name that is writable by your user if you need write access without changing users.

Comment: I tried to figure out which user runs my nginx with phusion passenger, so: `ps aux | grep nginx` -> `root` and `nobody`. I run the nginx via `sudo /opt/nginx/sbin/nginx` (installed with phusion passenger, no init.d script)

Comment: I solved the problem so: remove the tmp with `rm -rf .tmp` and recreate it again `mkdir tmp`, now no errors

Comment: awesome @static, you really made my made graceful. Exactly works on my system.

Comment: In my case, I opened up my IDE as a root user upon first installation, and then running web app caused some things in `tmp/` to be owned by root. Taking ownership of everything in `tmp/` solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this error was happening for me was because I was running

```
ruby bin/rails server
```

instead of

```
ruby bin/rails server -e development
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

rm -rf public/assets
 rake assets:clean RAILS_ENV=development

chown -R nginx:nginx /www/rblpt/