# Rails: NameError: uninitialized constant Bootsnap::CompileCache::ISeq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootsnap

I have a Ruby on Rails application that has been running fine for some time. Today, I added a few features to it and then started the application in a development environment, which started fine without errors. But when I try to access the application on my browser, I run into this error:

> NameError: uninitialized constant Bootsnap::CompileCache::ISeq>)

I have tried updating the Bootsnap gem to the latest version:

```
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.6'
```

Deleted the `Gemfile.lock` file

```
rm -rf Gemfile.lock
```

And then ran bundle update command to update the gems

```
bundle update
```

But no success yet, since I am still running into the same issue. Any form of help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally figured it out. I did **not** have to update the [Bootsnap](https://rubygems.org/gems/bootsnap) gem.

The problem is that [Bootsnap](https://rubygems.org/gems/bootsnap) gem `tmp` directory in your application directory is not writable to the current user, that is, the current user does not have permission to write to the [Bootsnap](https://rubygems.org/gems/bootsnap) gem `tmp` directory in your application directory.

**Here's how I solved it**:

Simply delete the [Bootsnap](https://rubygems.org/gems/bootsnap) gem `tmp` directory in your **application** directory with superuser rights:

```
sudo rm -rf tmp/cache/bootsnap-load-path-cache
sudo rm -rf tmp/cache/bootsnap-compile-cache
```

Do not recreate the `tmp` directory again, it's a waste of effort

Simply start your **application** and the `tmp` directory will be created automatically again:

```
rails s
```

If after this you encounter this error:

> Permission denied @ apply2files

Then follow the solution here: [Rails: “Permission denied - /tmp/cache/assets/development/sprockets/](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61251743/10907864)

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Comment: The key thing here is you need to be the `superuser`.  In my case with an SSH box I didn't have to clear the `tmp` folder, just login as the superuser in the SSH box e.g. with `sudo su nameofsuperuser` and rerun the migration/seed.